# ASPX - sort XML by 3 GridViews

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview, aspxgridview

OK! this one has got me in a bind.

I have an XML File with multiple entries, i want to put it into certain Gridviews by the inner text of 1 element. Here is my Code;

```
<asp:GridView ID="TicketViewURG" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="TicketView_RowDataBound" OnSorted="TicketViewURG_Sorted" Width="100%">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Time.Date" HeaderText="Created" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Reference" HeaderText="Ref No." />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="StoreID" HeaderText="Store I.D" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="completeStatus" HeaderText="Status" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ActionRequired" HeaderText="ActionRequired" />                        
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

                 <asp:GridView ID="TicketViewASAP" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="TicketView_RowDataBound" OnSorted="TicketViewURG_Sorted" Width="100%">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Time.Date" HeaderText="Created" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Reference" HeaderText="Ref No." />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="StoreID" HeaderText="Store I.D" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="completeStatus" HeaderText="Status" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ActionRequired" HeaderText="ActionRequired" />                        
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

                 <asp:GridView ID="TicketViewTODO" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="TicketView_RowDataBound" OnSorted="TicketViewURG_Sorted" Width="100%">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Time.Date" HeaderText="Created" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Reference" HeaderText="Ref No." />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="StoreID" HeaderText="Store I.D" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="completeStatus" HeaderText="Status" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ActionRequired" HeaderText="ActionRequired" />                        
                    </Columns>
```

This is what my XML Looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SupportTickets>
  <Ticket Time.Date="24/05/2016 08:32:53">
    <Reference>SAN3553</Reference>
    <StoreID>Test</StoreID>
    <Contact>Joanne</Contact>
    <Department>Shop</Department>
    <Description>TEST</Description>
    <ActionRequired>ASAP</ActionRequired>
    <completeStatus>Not Complete</completeStatus>
    <ID>1</ID>
  </Ticket>
  <Ticket Time.Date="24/05/2016 08:32:53">
    <Reference>SAN3553</Reference>
    <StoreID>Test</StoreID>
    <Contact>Joanne</Contact>
    <Department>Shop</Department>
    <Description>TEST. </Description>
    <ActionRequired>TODO</ActionRequired>
    <completeStatus>Not Complete</completeStatus>
    <ID>2</ID>
  </Ticket>
  <Ticket Time.Date="24/05/2016 08:32:53">
    <Reference>SAN3553</Reference>
    <StoreID>Test</StoreID>
    <Contact>Joanne</Contact>
    <Department>Shop</Department>
    <Description>TILL HAS STOPPED SCANNING NHS BARCODE. </Description>
    <ActionRequired>ASAP</ActionRequired>
    <completeStatus>Not Complete</completeStatus>
    <ID>3</ID>
  </Ticket>
</SupportTickets>
```

I want to pull from the XML the bound field names but sort them into the correct GridView,

So Entry No.1 in my XML will goto TicketViewURG because XML element ActionRequired has an inner text of ASAP.

The XML element i am trying this with is `<ActionRequired></ActionRequired>`

Answer (score 0):

Created a little method which does what you require.To get data for different grid views just pass through the index of the `<Ticket>` element:

```
List<Data> gridView1DS = this.GetData(doc,0);
List<Data> gridView2DS = this.GetData(doc,1);
List<Data> gridView3DS = this.GetData(doc,3);
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class BindXmlToGridView : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument doc = this.LoadXmlDoc("input.xml");

        List<Data> gridView1DS = this.GetData(doc, 0);

        TicketViewURG.DataSource = gridView1DS;
        TicketViewURG.DataBind();
    }

    private List<Data> GetData(XDocument doc,int ticketIndex)
    {
        var list = new List<Data>();
        var d = new Data();

        XElement element = doc.Elements("SupportTickets").Elements().ElementAt(ticketIndex);

        d.TimeDate = element.Attribute("Time.Date").Value;
        d.Reference = element.Element("Reference").Value;
        d.StoreID = element.Element("StoreID").Value;
        d.Department = element.Element("Department").Value;
        d.completeStatus = element.Element("completeStatus").Value;
        d.ActionRequired = element.Element("ActionRequired").Value;

        list.Add(d);

        return list;
    }

    private XDocument LoadXmlDoc(string fileName)
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName));
        return xmlDoc;
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public string TimeDate { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public string StoreID { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ActionRequired { get; set; }
    public string completeStatus { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="TicketViewURG" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeDate" HeaderText="Created" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Reference" HeaderText="Ref No." />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StoreID" HeaderText="Store I.D" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="completeStatus" HeaderText="Status" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ActionRequired" HeaderText="ActionRequired" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Output:**
[image: Bind XML to grid]